# remove time from a date like this 2016-02-10 00:00:00

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

hello I have a date like this

```
2016-02-10 00:00:00
```

I want to get only date from it in this style

```
14.05.2016 or 14-05-2016
```

This is what I have tried

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let date = "2016-02-10 00:00:00"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let newdate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)
print(newdate) //nil is coming
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

okay I solved this myself

```
  let date = "2016-02-10 00:00:00"
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
  let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)!
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
  let datenew= dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString)

    print(datenew)
```

Comment: Seem inefficient to use strings / dateformatter for date math.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is you should convert your String `date` "2016-02-10 00:00:00" to Date type first.

Answer (score 44):

A better way than proposed versions is not to convert from date using a string formatter, but instead using calendar:

```
public func removeTimeStamp(fromDate: Date) -> Date {
    guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: fromDate)) else {
        fatalError("Failed to strip time from Date object")
    }
    return date
}
```

Comment: Please check out this post that suggests your solution would not work due to consideration for Timezones.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7416905

Answer (score 19):

Using an extension on the Date:

```
extension Date {
    public var removeTimeStamp : Date? {
       guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)) else {
        return nil
       }
       return date
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
let now = Date()
let nowWithouTime = now.removeTimeStamp
```

Comment: Thanx exactly what i needed in conjunction to check if a date is between two dates without the time

Comment: Might be worth to mention, that Calendar's timeZone property should set appropriately

Answer (score 6):

## Swift 5.5+

Use `formatted(_:)`

```
let now = Date.now
let date = now.formatted(.iso8601.year().month().day().dateSeparator(.dash))
```

Or `formatted(date:time:)`

```
let now = Date.now
let date = now.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)
```

Instead of `.abbreviated`, you may use a DateStyle such as `.long`, or `.numeric`.

https://developer.apple.com

Comment: Very elegant, but bear in mind Date.now works starting from iOS 15

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not correct.

If you have `NSDate` instance that you want to convert to String using `NSDateFormatter`

You use this code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

The problem in your code is that you have a date string with value `2016-02-10 00:00:00` but you parse it using date format `dd-MM-yyyy' this is why you get a nil Date.

Instead you need to parse it first using `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an input date string (or rather, date-and-time string) in one format and you want to output in a different format then you need 2 date formatters: An input formatter that takes the source string format and converts it to an NSDate (using `dateFromString`) and then an output formatter that takes the NSDate and converts it to your output date string (using `stringFromDate`).

Your code is wrong because you are creating a date formatter configured for your output date string format and trying to use it to convert your input date string to an NSDate.

I am not an expert on NSDateFormatter date strings. Any time I need to work with them I have to dig out the docs and figure out the solution to the specific problem I'm trying to solve. Thus I'm going to leave that part of the problem to you. Suffice it to say that you'll need an input date formatter that uses a format string that **exactly** matches the format of your input date string. This can be tricky because if it isn't exactly correct it simply fails and returns a nil NSDate.
The output date formatter is easier because if it isn't quite right, your output date will not look the way you want it to look but that will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you to use library [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) with dozen of handy options.
For your case use date truncating e.g.:

```
let date = "2017-07-22 15:03:50".toDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", region: rome)
let truncatedTime = date.dateTruncated(from: .hour) // 2017-07-22T00:00:00+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 and above, You can go with the following code

```
 let date = "2016-02-10 00:00:00"
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 let date = modelDeals.dealItemInDetail?.validTo ?? ""
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
 let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as NSDate
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
 let datenew = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString as Date)
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3 Version:

```
let date = "2016-02-10"
let dateformater = DateFormatter()
    dateformater.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
    let dateString = dateformater.date(from: date)

    //print date
    print(dateString)
```

Answer (score -1):

For [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) : (Swift 3) applications,

if you are using `Date()` objects make sure you set `timeStyle`
of `DateFormatter()` to `none`

Example:

```
let today = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd", upto you
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
//This is Important!
dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateTimeFormatter.Style.none
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
```