# Swift convert string to date output wrong date

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3

I want to convert `dateStartString = “28/02/2018”` in to `Date` and compare that converted date with today date. when i convert `dateStartString` the converted date is `"2018-02-27 18:30:00 UTC"`.why its output is wrong date?

**here is my code**

```
var dateStartString = "28/02/2018"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
guard let dateStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStartString) else {
    fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
}

let dateToday = Date()

if(dateStartDate>=dateToday){
    print("Yes")
}
else{
    print("Today date is 28/02/2018. Why it print No?")
}
```

Hope you understand my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which time zone are you in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that `Date` does not only represent a date, but also a *time*.

`>=` compares both date and time components of a `Date` object. Since you didn't specified any time in your date string, the API assumed it to be 00:00:00 in your local time, which is 18:30:00 of the previous day in UTC. Why UTC, you ask? That's what the `description` of the date always is. When you print a date, it always prints it in UTC time. To print it in your time zone, set the `timeZone` property of your date formatter and format it.

One way to only compare the date components is by removing the time components. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392538/remove-time-from-a-date-like-this-2016-02-10-000000), this is how you remove time components:

```
public func removeTimeStamp(fromDate: Date) -> Date {
    guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: fromDate)) else {
        fatalError("Failed to strip time from Date object")
    }
    return date
}
```

Now this should be true:

```
dateStartDate >= removeTimeStamp(fromDate: dateToday)
```

Comment: Thank you.I got it.It is Working Fine

Answer (score 1):

As [Sweeper explained,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023964/1187415) `dateStartDate` is at `00:00` of `28/02/2018`,
whereas `dateToday` is the current point in time, which is
on the same day, but *after* midnight. Therefore `dateStartDate >= dateToday` evaluates to `false`.

To compare the timestamps only to day granularity and ignore the
time components you can use

```
if Calendar.current.compare(dateStartDate, to: dateToday, toGranularity: .day) != .orderedAscending {
    print("Yes")
}
```

This will print "Yes" if `dateStartDate` is on the same or a later
day than `dateToday`.

The compare method returns `.orderedAscending`, `.orderedSame`,
or `.orderedDescending`, depending on wether the first date is on
a previous day, the same day, or a later day, than the second date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `timeZone` for your `dateFormatter`:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0)!
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set your current date Formatter while comapring date.
Below your sample code update:

```
var dateStartString = "28/02/2018"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
guard let dateStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStartString) else {
    fatalError("ERROR: Date conversion failed due to mismatched format.")
}

var dateToday = Date()
print(dateToday)
let dateTodaystr = dateFormatter.string(from: dateToday)
dateToday = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTodaystr)!
print(dateToday)

if(dateStartDate>=dateToday){
    print("Yes")
}
else{
    print("Today date is 28/02/2018. Why it print No?")
}
```