# Remove only time from array of dates Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting dates from an api like this:

```
["2019-07-12 12:43:00", "2019-07-09 12:57:35", "2019-07-09 12:04:33", "2019-07-05 14:32:32", "2019-07-04 17:50:23", "2019-07-02 12:12:30", "2019-07-01 18:09:28"]
```

but what I want is I want to remove the time from this array of dates to get the dates like this

I want my desired result like this

```
["2019-07-12", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-04", "2019-07-02", "2019-07-01"]
```

The reason why I want because I need to show the events on `FSCalendar`. How can I do this?

Comment: Are that all strings? Do they have a fixed format? Can you just take the first 10 characters? – You surely tried something, don't hesitate to show your attempt!

Comment: convert it using date formatter

Comment: @MartinR....Yes they all are the strings and the format comes same to all dates and I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392538/remove-time-from-a-date-like-this-2016-02-10-000000 but t showed the fatal error

Comment: if all are strings use [split strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/split-a-string-into-an-array-in-swift) and store the first object into array thats all

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik... I seen that answer but all of them are just splitting  a variable of string  not  array

Comment: @Wings make sure your strings are local time otherwise (if they are UTC time)  you would need to parse your dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a combination of **`compactMap(_:)`** and **`components(separatedBy:)`** like,

```
let arr = ["2019-07-12 12:43:00", "2019-07-09 12:57:35", "2019-07-09 12:04:33", "2019-07-05 14:32:32", "2019-07-04 17:50:23", "2019-07-02 12:12:30", "2019-07-01 18:09:28"]

let result = arr.compactMap({ $0.components(separatedBy: " ").first })
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code:

```
    let arr = ["2019-07-12 12:43:00", "2019-07-09 12:57:35", "2019-07-09 12:04:33", "2019-07-05 14:32:32", "2019-07-04 17:50:23", "2019-07-02 12:12:30", "2019-07-01 18:09:28"]

    var arrOnlyDates = [String]()
    for (_,str) in arr.enumerated(){
        let s = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
        arrOnlyDates.append(s[0])
    }
    print(arrOnlyDates)
```

Comment: Why use `enumerated()` if you only discard the offset?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get dates array like this:

```
let dateArray = ["2019-07-12 12:43:00", "2019-07-09 12:57:35", "2019-07-09 12:04:33", "2019-07-05 14:32:32", "2019-07-04 17:50:23", "2019-07-02 12:12:30", "2019-07-01 18:09:28"]

let onlyDatesArray = dateArray.compactMap({ $0.components(separatedBy: " ")[0] })

print("only dates -> \(onlyDatesArray)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateStrings = ["2019-07-12 12:43:00", "2019-07-09 12:57:35", "2019-07-09 12:04:33", "2019-07-05 14:32:32", "2019-07-04 17:50:23", "2019-07-02 12:12:30", "2019-07-01 18:09:28"]    
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dates = dateStrings.compactMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let formatedDateStrings = dates.compactMap { dateFormatter.string(from: $0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the date format doesn't change just strip the first 10 characters from each string

```
let dates = ["2019-07-12 12:43:00", "2019-07-09 12:57:35", "2019-07-09 12:04:33", "2019-07-05 14:32:32", "2019-07-04 17:50:23", "2019-07-02 12:12:30", "2019-07-01 18:09:28"]
let datesWithoutTime = dates.map{ String($0.prefix(10)) }
```